# Assistance listing query names from many (~100) ms access databases

Tags: ms-access

I have inherited responsibility for the management of our org's client management system. Data is in ms-sql, data entry is done via .net custom screens, and reporting is done via ms-access.

My predecessor (who never had much tech training) responded to user requests for data by building queries in ms-access, exporting the data and sending the data as an email attachment. What with various attempts to organize things over the years, .mdb's corrupting, and other issues, there are now around 100 .mdb files with his queries in them. Each of the mdbs may have around 100 queries.

Now, users will email me with the attachment he sent them and say "your predecessor created this report for me a few months ago. Can you run it again?" I can see the name of the query because it is the name of the exported excel file. I go and open the .mdb files he used most and look for the query name but am unable to find many of them.

Any ideas of how I could run something against the entire folder directory of .mdb files to get a list of all queries in the .mdb files?

Any ideas are welcome, thanks much.

Comment: Each database has a [QueryDefs collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydefs-collection-dao).  Using VBA, you can loop through the collection and retrieve the name of each `QueryDef`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *Dir* to loop the filenames:

```vb
Public Function ListQueries()

    Const Path      As String = "C:\Test\"

    Dim Workspace   As DAO.Workspace
    Dim Database    As DAO.Database
    Dim Query       As DAO.QueryDef

    Dim Filename    As String

    Set Workspace = DBEngine(0)

    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.mdb", vbNormal)
    While Filename <> ""
        Debug.Print Filename

        Set Database = Workspace.OpenDatabase(Path & Filename, , True)
        For Each Query In Database.QueryDefs
            If Asc(Query.Name) <> 126 Then
                Debug.Print , Query.Name
            End If
        Next
        Database.Close

        Filename = Dir
    Wend

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This does what I need!